# Understanding Django's ORM (Database Design with ForeignKey and QuerySets)

Tags: django, django-orm

I need some help wrapping my head around Django 1.8's ORM.  I am confused as to how I should implement relationships in the database correctly.

I want a `User` object to have one `UserProfile`. I also need a `User` to be able to make several `Posts`.

Then I want `UserProfile` to have access to all posts made *by* a user so that I can display them in a `userprofile` view.   Should I do this by giving `Post` a FK to `UserProfile` or the other way around or at all?

And if this is the correct way, how would I even QuerySet all the posts by a user?
Here is the code for my models so far:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.user.username)


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.title)
```

I think I may be over-thinking all this.  I have a suspicion that `UserProfile` and `Post` don't need a relationship at all and the view can just render separate data with these two QuerySets like these?
 `posts=Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)` and 
`user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a user_profile FK on Post model.
If you want to get access to all posts created by a User in order to display them on UserProfile, you can use this query, given a user_profile instance:

```
user_posts = user_profile.user.post_set.all()
```

`user_profile` has a user attribute because of the OneToOne field, which has a `post_set` attribute, which is already linked to your user and gives you all posts created by that user. Moreover, the post_set is a queryset as well, which means you can filter on it too:

```
user_profile.user.post_set.filter(title__icontains='Django')
```

The above code will give you all posts of the given `user_profile` that have 'django' in their title.

For further reference, consult django documentation on [related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) and [following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: wow awesome.  So If I was to render them through a view, I would have to pass the `request.user` argument through the QuerySet somehow right?  Something like `user_profile.user.post_set.all(instance=request.user)`?

Comment: what exactly do you want to render through a view? In case it is the Posts, you can go with `Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)`, but in order to accomplish this you don't need the relationship between Post and UserProfile.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes a lot of sense now.  That answers everything, thanks!

Comment: one more thing... it is a good practice to define a `related_name` argument on ForeignKey relationships, like in Post model - `user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, related_name='posts')`. Thus, your query will look like `user_profile.user.posts.all()`, which is more clear and easy to understand.